# VS2013 package error with missing type, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsToolboxItemProvider, even though its not used

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vsx, vs-extensibility

I'm trying to exclude 10.0 interop assemblies from my LanguageService and Package.

> Cannot find the interop type that matches the embedded interop type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsToolboxItemProvider'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

My package does not use this type. 
The language service has references to 10.0 and 12.0 interops assemblies. 
I'm trying to exclude the 10.0 version but I get the error above.
And apparently the type should exist in 12.0
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivstoolboxitemprovider.aspx